# Calculating the number of arrangements of items into compartments?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

I'm dealing with intro combinatorics here, and am a bit perplexed by the logic around arranging items in boxes. When arranging a small set of objects in a series of boxes, I am not seeing why the arrangement in the boxes reduces the number of total arrangements.

In looking at this, I am given the formula of:

```
n!/(n1! x ... x nk!), where n1 + ... + nk = n
```

For example, the ways of arranging 3 balls in a row is: 3! = 6. This is interpreted as the total number of arrangements n!/(n-k)! where k=3 is the number of objects permuted for n=3 objects in total, so for balls A, B, and C, we get:

```
ABC
ACB
BAC
BCA
CAB
CBA
```

However, if we have two boxes available, Box A that will hold two balls, and Box B that will hold only one ball, the ways of arranging them are:

```
Box A   Box B
AB      C
AC      B
BA      C
BC      A
CA      B
CB      A
```

This appears to be 6 arrangements, assuming AB and BA are considered different arrangements; however, when plugged into the formula I get:

```
3!/(2!x1!) = 3*2*1/(2*1x1) = 3
```

Why does this equation come up with half of the expected arrangements?

Comment: That formula, which you are asking about, is normally used for this question: How many words can you make of the three letters AAB (thinking of them as scrabble tiles)? The answer is 3 -- there 3!=6 orderings of the tiles, but you must divide by 2!=2 since each distinct "word" corresponds to 2 tile orderings obtained by the different orderings of the A tiles. Try it for the scrabble tiles BARBARA ...

Answer (score 1):

The best thing you can do in the second case is, find the number of ways you can choose 2 balls out of 3(to put in the bigger box) and multiply it with the number of ways you can choose 1 ball out of 1 i.e 1
The answer'll be 3C2*1C1=3.
The question doesn't require you to arrange the two balls in the bigger box in a specific order whereas in the first case it's like arranging 3 different digits in 3 places.In that case you must take order into account.

Comment: Ok that makes sense (thanks!), but my biggest frustration here is how to tell when arrangement in such boxes are required? By using combinations as you suggest, this indicates AB = BA for the first box, which works if that's required, but when the problem is simply stated as "arrange items in these boxes," it does not say whether permutations are acceptable, or whether combinations are needed. I'm a bit perplexed as to how to distinguish this, especially in problems that end up using both. Its something that's not always clear (as might be illustrated in this case).

Comment: When you put two balls ,red and black for example, in a box or a bag , to put them in order doesn't make any sense.However if you are arranging two paintings on a wall,order is required(which one on left and which one on right) or take the box itself, to arrange the two balls in an order will only make sense if the box has a partition or something. Try to visualize the situation. You'll understand.